# Moshi ignore field

Tags: json, moshi

Is there a simple way to ignore a field when using moshi to serialize to a json string? I can only think about is a custom adapter - but I have the feeling that there is a better way

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `transient` on the field declaration.

```
private transient String your_variable_name;
```

Originally I found [Exclude fields from serialization and deserialization](https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/94)

Hope It's help you.

Comment: Thanks  - you get the bounty but I have to wait 22h

Comment: Glade to know it helped you. :)

Comment: How to do it in kotlin?

Comment: @GregEnnis add the `@Transient` annotation

Comment: Sorry, my question is actually: How to do it in Kotlin on a lazy property? Moshi chokes on lazy properties, and Transient cannot be applied to a property. So I'm stuck @RobCo

Comment: `@IgnoredOnParcel @delegate:Transient val firstName by lazy { computeFirstName() }`

Comment: transient is a terrible use, because it's also picked up and interpreted by other systems. You need a way to tell Moshi to ignore a field without making it transient.