# Moshi ignore field in Kotlin

Tags: json, kotlin, serialization, moshi

I want to know how to ignore a Kotlin class field when using Moshi.

I've found this answer for Java ([Moshi ignore field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36204499/moshi-ignore-field)), that indicates to use the keyword transient as follows

```
private transient String your_variable_name;
```

But I can't find the right way to get this done in Kotlin.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Use the `@Transient` annotation.

```
@Transient
private val your_variable_name: String
```

Doc here: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-transient/index.html

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks!!

Comment: This is not working when expected fields do not come in JSON response.

Comment: Also, make sure you provide a default value. Otherwise, it might throw an error.

Answer (score 3):

Kotlin + Retrofit + Moshi

In case where you want to conditionally ignore fields, you can set it to null.

```
data class  User(var id: String,  var name: string?)

val user = User()
user.id = "some id"
user.name = null
```

The Json generated would be

```
user{
"id": "some id"
}
```

Comment: Ie:  
```@Transient @Json(name= "snow") val snowVolume: Int? = null```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way

```
@field:Json(ignore = true)
val your_variable_name: String
```

Comment: Does not seem to have the `ignore` param for Json

Comment: It was added recently. Try updating your Moshi version

Comment: I am pretty sure about this. [Moshi Json Documentation](https://square.github.io/moshi/1.x/moshi/moshi/com.squareup.moshi/-json/index.html)

Comment: Not sure about the doc. But here is the [source](https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/master/moshi/src/main/java/com/squareup/moshi/Json.kt)

Comment: it was added to master but is not yet in a release. The [github readme](https://github.com/square/moshi) is misleading in the sense that you're viewing the docs for master unless you specifically switch to [a release branch](https://github.com/square/moshi/tree/moshi-parent-1.13.0)