# What the equivalent of @JsonIgnoreProperties with moshi?

Tags: android, json, moshi

What's the equivalent of the annotation `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` for Moshi? Does it ignore unknown properties by default or not?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36204499/moshi-ignore-field

Comment: I don't want to exclude a specific field, I want to exclude all fields that are not declared in my POJO class, so that it doesn't break on api changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moshi by default ignore's properties that are not declared in POJO's and are present in JSON without throwing any error.

Incase failure is desired in such case, `failOnUnknown` has to be set explicitly on the adapter.

For e.g.
`Moshi.Builder().build().adapter(MyClass::class.java).failOnUnknown()`